# Standard or convention for DateTime to [A-Z] string conversion?

Tags: date, datetime, encoding

I like to use `DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")` as a unique-*enough* salt for padding instead of a random string or GUID in tests for easier debugging and sorting. However I can't use it where validation only allows alpha character strings, e.g. a name (where '[Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)' is ignored).

Is there a standard or a convention to encode a timestamp as a [A-Z]+ string? Preferably something more efficient than roman numerals but still **human readable**, i.e. not a base64-like lookup-table-based variant but a logic-based one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with a lookup using a mix of [leet speak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leet) and [calculator spelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculator_spelling) forgoing sorting in lieu of readability.

- http://www.wikihow.com/Sample/1337-Cheat-Sheet
- http://www.wikihow.com/Sample/Calculator-Letter-List
- http://www.inversoft.com/blog/2013/08/28/profanity-filtering-101-character-replacements-leet-speak/

```cs
var map = new Dictionary<char, char>
{
    { '0', 'O' },
    { '1', 'I' },
    { '2', 'Z' },
    { '3', 'E' },
    { '4', 'A' },
    { '5', 'S' },
    { '6', 'G' },
    { '7', 'T' },
    { '8', 'B' },
    { '9', 'P' }
};
return string.Concat(value.Select(c => map[c]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of, but if you treat `A` as `0` and `J` as `9` you can simply replace all numbers from the `yyyyMMddHHmmss` string.

Comment: Thanks, it's not very readable though as I'm not proficient with vigesimal systems.